# error TS1127: Invalid character when running Karma tests in Angular 7

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngentest

- I'm getting errors `error TS1127: Invalid character` in the Visual Studio Code terminal, when running a Karma test for an Angular 7 app
- **CLI version** - `7.3.9`
- I have *one single Karma test specification* in the app
- (I removed all of the `spec` files that the Angular CLI generates, but left the existing Jasmine and Karma npm packages in place)
- Jasmine is the test runner
- This doesn't seem to be an invalid character or whitespace issue - this didn't work - [Angular compile error: src/app/login/login.component.ts(18,10): error TS1127: Invalid > character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584678/angular-compile-error-src-app-login-login-component-ts18-10-error-ts1127-in)

I generated the test automatically using [ngentest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngentest)

To generate a test using ngentest, do this from the Visual Studio Code terminal, on Windows:

```
npm install ngentest -g # to run this command anywhere
ngentest app.component.ts > # write unit test to app.component.spec.ts
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
// tslint:disable
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Injectable, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import {Component, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {DataService} from './services/data.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {LocaleService} from './services/locale.service';
import {BsLocaleService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Injectable()
class MockDataService { }

@Injectable()
class MockLocaleService { }

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: DataService, useClass: MockDataService},
        ToastrService,
        {provide: LocaleService, useClass: MockLocaleService},
        BsLocaleService,
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create a component', async () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run #ngOnInit()', async () => {
    // const result = component.ngOnInit();
  });

  it('should run #ngOnDestroy()', async () => {
    // const result = component.ngOnDestroy();
  });

});
```

run the tests from the CLI using:

- `npm install`
- `npm run build`
- `ng test`

`app.component.spec.ts TS1127: Invalid character` errors then display in the console

this appears in the Karma test report viewer that runs in Chrome:

`Incomplete: No specs found, , randomized with seed 42068`

I tried running `npm install –save-dev jasmine`, which added `"jasmine": "^3.4.0"`. I did an `npm install`, build and `ng test` again - same issue

---

The `devDependencies` in `package.json` are now:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.7",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-i18nsupport": "^0.17.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

---

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled all of the jasmine and karma related `devDependencies` and reinstalled them, and also did an `npm install ngentest` (it wasn't installed but the generation from the CLI worked without this). I then ran an `npm install`. I then removed app.component.spec.ts and did `npm run build`. I then did:

```
ngentest app.component.ts > app.component.spec.ts
npm run build
ng test
```

same error

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem the one and only time I used gentest from vscode.
Simple workaround: Use gentest from command line directly.

Problem and resolution: Open the created .spec file in notepad++ and covert encoding from whatever weird stuff vscode chose for you and save to UTF-8.